# How to use VBA in Outlook to create a macro to resize an image

Tags: vba, outlook

As noted in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721597/how-to-set-default-size-of-pictures-pasted-into-outlook-from-the-snipping-tool) of mine, Outlook is pasting screen grabs from the Snipping Tool in a default size of 125% x 125%, whereas I'd like it to be 100% x 100%. In lieu of actually changing the default setting, I'd like to make a macro to resize the image.

I've done similar things in VBA PowerPoint, but each application seems to be different. For example, I tried the code

```
Sub Resize_Outlook4()
    With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
        .ScaleHeight = 150
        .ScaleWidth = 150
    End With
End Sub
```

following an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173656%28v=office.11%29.aspx), which should resize all the inline shapes to 150% x 150%, but this leads to an error "Run-time error '424': Object required".

In short, I'm having trouble specifying an Object which would represent the currently selected picture, or just all the pictures in the e-mail. Does anybody know how to do this correctly?

Comment: `ActiveDocument` is an object within the MS Word object model.  You would need to refer to a specific `MailItem` object. To be honest: I think the *correct* way to do this would be to change the default settings.  There is no need for a macro to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work, but I still recommend simply changing the default settings...

```
Sub Resize150()

    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim shp As Object
    'Get the word-editor of the mail item
    If Application.ActiveInspector Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set objDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    For Each shp In objDoc.InlineShapes
        If shp.HasPicture Then
            shp.ScaleHeight = 150
            shp.ScaleWidth = 150
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```